# How to process an image (BufferedImage) using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing

I'm trying to use multithreading to make a program faster.

Right now the simple code is like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < dither.getHeight() - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < dither.getWidth() - 1; x++) {

            Color pixel = new Color(dither.getRGB(x, y));

            int oldR = pixel.getRed();
            int oldG = pixel.getGreen();
            int oldB = pixel.getBlue();

            int newR = findClosestPalleteColor(oldR, factor);
            int newG = findClosestPalleteColor(oldG, factor);
            int newB = findClosestPalleteColor(oldB, factor);

            int errR = oldR - newR;
            int errG = oldG - newG;
            int errB = oldB - newB;

            dither.setRGB(x, y, new Color(newR, newG, newB).getRGB());

            try {
                dither.setRGB(x + 1, y    , (quantize(new Color(dither.getRGB(x + 1, y    )), errR, errG, errB, 7)).getRGB());
                dither.setRGB(x - 1, y + 1, (quantize(new Color(dither.getRGB(x - 1, y + 1)), errR, errG, errB, 3)).getRGB());
                dither.setRGB(x    , y + 1, (quantize(new Color(dither.getRGB(x    , y + 1)), errR, errG, errB, 5)).getRGB());
                dither.setRGB(x + 1, y + 1, (quantize(new Color(dither.getRGB(x + 1, y + 1)), errR, errG, errB, 1)).getRGB());
            }catch (Exception e) {}

        }
    }
```

dither is a BufferedImage object.

It's a dithering program, and it works fine until the image is big.
What is the best way to divide this process to different threads?

One thing I tried is to make sub images, process them and put them back together, but I don't know how to put them back together! So if this is a good idea, help me with that please.

Comment: Using "sub images" is indeed most times the best way to handle this. But instead of some real sub images, like 4 quarter images, you better use a "scan-line interleave" method, meaning each thread calculates another line of the image. For example, you have 4 threads, so thread 1 calculates line (1 + 4*n), thread 2 calculates line (2 + 4*n), thread 3 calculates line (3 + 4*n), thread 4 calculates line (4 + 4*n), where n is a natural number (inclusive zero). Java has a large number of image manipulating methods aiding in your task.

Comment: @paladin thanks, this made it a lot easier.